# Maven-surefire is not running Spock tests annotated with @Tag

Tags: groovy, spock, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm trying to run only some of my Spock tests. To do so I use JUnit5 @Tag annotation. However, Spock tests with this annotation are not visible to maven-surefire whereas JUnit5 tests are.

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>cz.diribet</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-bom</artifactId>
                <version>5.8.1</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                <artifactId>groovy-bom</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.8</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0-groovy-3.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <groups>my-tag</groups>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-compile</id>
                        <phase>process-test-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <source>13</source>
                            <target>13</target>
                            <compilerId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</compilerId>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>

                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                        <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</artifactId>
                        <version>3.7.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                        <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-batch</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.8-01</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

</project>
```

JUnitTest.java

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Tag;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

@Tag("my-tag")
public class JUnitTest {

    @Test
    public void simpleTest() {
        Assertions.assertEquals(1, 1);
    }
}
```

SpockTest.groovy

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Tag
import spock.lang.Specification

@Tag("my-tag")
class SpockTest extends Specification {

    def "simple test"() {
        expect:
        1 == 1
    }
}
```

running with simple `mvn test` I get results

```
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running JUnitTest
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.063 s - in JUnitTest
[INFO]
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  5.442 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-11-03T11:49:38+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I use OpenJDK17, Maven 3.8.3, Windows 10

Comment: Why do you compile your main sources with Java 17 but your tests with Java 13?

Comment: Because groovy-eclipse-compiler I use to compile groovy tests does not support Java 17 yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Spock doesn't have anything to do with `org.junit.jupiter.api.*`, so `@Tag` doesn't work either.

See Spock's way of [including/excluding tests](https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.0/all_in_one.html#_include_and_exclude).

Comment: There is an interesting [issue](https://github.com/spockframework/spock/issues/1288) related to this problem